# Page_Init and Page_Load

Tags: asp.net, webforms

A page containts custom address control and checkBox. Why does the second example of code work properly, but first doesn't?

```
//1
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //doesn't work properly
   ucLegalAddress.Visible = !chkLegalAddress.Checked;
}


 //2
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //works properly
     ucLegalAddress.Visible = !chkLegalAddress.Checked;
   }
```

Comment: plz g through this http://codeasp.net/articles/aspnet-page-lifecycle/20/asp.net. if it helps you understand the concept well

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the viewstate of the controls is loaded between the init and the load event. This means that the init event does not know the state of the client yet.

[MSDN lifecycle overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Because all controls are create in OnInit() method, that call between Page_Init and Page_Load. In Page_Init all controls are null. [Read more](http://www.google.ru/search?q=ASP.NET%20Page%20Lifecycle&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=ru.yandex%3aru%3aofficial&client=firefox)

Comment: Not `null` actually. They have their default properties.